# Custom color gradient for multiple GAM plots using Gratia

Tags: r, mgcv

I fitted a GAM model which includes two tensor smooths, using mgcv package. All variables except 'season' are numeric in nature.

```
library(mgcv)
# Fit the GAM model
gam_model <- gam(
  score ~ te(duration, difference) + te(duration, temperature) + season,
  data = my_data
)
```

Then I plotted the model to see the partial effects, using draw() function from gratia package and it plots fine. However I want to change the color gradient such that it is red for low values and green for high values. I tried the below code for the same.

```
gam_plot <- gratia::draw(gam_model, contour = FALSE)
gam_plot + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
```

However, the color gradient is getting applied only for the second tensor product and the first one has the default blue to red gradient.

I then tried splitting & plotting them based on the interaction name,

```
# Draw the first interaction term with custom color
plot1 <- gratia::draw(gam_model, terms = "te(duration, difference)", contour = FALSE)
plot1 <- plot1 + ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
print(plot1)

# Draw the second interaction term with custom color
plot2 <- gratia::draw(gam_model, terms = "te(duration, temperature)", contour = FALSE)
plot2 <- plot2 + ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
print(plot2)
```

But still, both print the two plots together as I had earlier i.e. one with color gradient changed and other without.

Moreover all the above plots come with a warning

```
Scale for fill is already present.
Adding another scale for fill, which will replace the existing scale.
```

Appreciate your help in getting both plots with red -> green gradient. Thank you

Comment: This is not the right place for questions about software (there's not much here that would rise to a statistical question). I've voted to close to send it to [so], but left an answer so that follows along with it.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library("mgcv")
library("dplyr")
library("readr")
library("gratia")

data_url <- "https://github.com/gavinsimpson/intro-gam-webinar-2020/raw/master/data/gbtemp.csv"

galveston <- read_csv(data_url) |>
    mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(DATE, TIME), format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', tz = "CDT"),
           STATION_ID = factor(STATION_ID), DoY = as.numeric(format(datetime, format = '%j')),
           ToD = as.numeric(format(datetime, format = '%H')) +
               (as.numeric(format(datetime, format = '%M')) / 60))

knots <- list(DoY = c(0.5, 366.5))
m <- bam(MEASUREMENT ~
             s(ToD, k = 10) +
             s(DoY, k = 12, bs = 'cc') +
             s(YEAR, k = 30) +
             s(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, k = 100, bs = 'ds', m = c(1, 0.5)) +
             ti(DoY, YEAR, bs = c('cc', 'tp'), k = c(12, 15)) +
             ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, ToD, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','tp'),
                m = list(c(1, 0.5), NA), k = c(20, 10)) +
             ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, DoY, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','cc'),
                m = list(c(1, 0.5), NA), k = c(25, 12)) +
             ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, YEAR, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','tp'),
                m = list(c(1, 0.5), NA), k = c(25, 15)),
         data = galveston, method = 'fREML', knots = knots,
         nthreads = c(4, 1), discrete = TRUE)
```

One way in general to change all the plots in the patchwork is to use the `&` operator:

```
draw(m, n = 25, rug = FALSE) &
  ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
```

but this is noisy (note all the messages from `ggplot`) as you are forcing the replacement of the scales. Instead, `draw.gam()` has arguments to change these aesthetics. In this case use `continuous_fill`:

```
draw(m, n = 25, rug = FALSE,
  continuous_fill = ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") )
```

That said, I would rethink doing this. You are plotting a surface with a natural 0 point and as such a diverging colour palette would be most appropriate. With your red-green gradient it is much harder to judge the 0 point (which is the overall average of the data). Then there's the problems such a scale would cause for many individuals with certain colour vision deficiencies.